# Anyone have a large folder tree sample?

Tags: testing, tree

I'm doing some testing that requires a large folder tree. 1000s of folders, 100000s of files, atleast a gigabyte but not over 5 thats a little big. (around 2 is fine).

Anyone have one that they use as a test file? I can provide storage and transfer mechanism to share if you need it.

Comment: Generate it. That's not hard.

Comment: i need it to have a normal use distribution. i dont want 'random' or whatever a computer program thinks is 'normal'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to generate random data, then you can, for example, download the [DMoz database](http://www.dmoz.org/rdf.html), it's an enormously big XML file with a tree in it, then parse it and generate a directory tree that follows the structure of the DMoz directory. You will have a meaningful and huge directory of files.